# Exchange Server 2007 SP3 Mail Sending Problem

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I installed Exchange Server 2007 SP3, and when I send an email I get an error.

Here is my error message.

```
Microsoft Exchange couldn't read the configuration from the Active Directory directory service because of error: Failed to load config due to exception: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADTransientException: Active Directory operation failed on server.techsoft.local. The supplied credential for 'MAILSERVER\Administrator' on Bind operation is invalid. Error Code: 0x31. ---> Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADInvalidCredentialException: Active Directory operation failed on server.techsoft.local. The supplied credential for 'MAILSERVER\Administrator' on Bind operation is invalid. Error Code: 0x31. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The supplied credential is invalid.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.BindWithRetry(Int32 maxRetries)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.BindWithRetry(Int32 maxRetries)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.LdapConnectionPool.CreateOneTimeConnection(NetworkCredential networkCredential, ADServerInfo serverInfo)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.PopulateConfigNamingContexts()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.GetConfigurationNamingContext()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCreator, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCreator)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCtor, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCtor)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ADSystemConfigurationSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ADSystemConfigurationSession.FindServerByFqdn(String serverFqdn)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.ADSystemConfigurationSession.FindLocalServer()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.LocalServerConfiguration.c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADNotificationAdapter.RunADOperation(ADOperation adOperation, Int32 retryCount)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADNotificationAdapter.RunADOperation(ADOperation adOperation, Int32 retryCount)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADNotificationAdapter.TryRunADOperation(ADOperation adOperation, Int32 retryCount).
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: here at Server Fault, "bumping" your posts by posting an answer is not how we do things. If you have more information to add, you can always edit your question and it will then go to the top of the front page again.

Comment: Don't worry about it - we were all new once :-) If you haven't already, you might want to give the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) a quick read. Hope you get an answer to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your ad server? Is it on the same machine?

The part

> The supplied credential for 'MAILSERVER\Administrator' on Bind operation is invalid.

...concerns me a little. Especially when the rest of the error says your AD server is 'server.techsoft.local'. It looks like exchange is trying to query AD with 'MAILSERVER\Administrator' (local admin) which AD would have no knowledge of (unless AD is local to the machine and the domain actually is 'MAILSERVER' making Administrator the domain administrator...). Can you check the user roles on the server (Organization Configuration screen)?

Have you run the BPA tools in the toolbox?